# Detailed Noise level datasets

Tags: audio

We are researching adaptive techniques for estimating longer-term soundlevels LAeq_T, from short-term soundlevels LAeq_tau. T is typically T=15minutes, and tau=1 seconds. To validate our approach we are in need of datasets of sufficient resolution.

Therefore we are looking for sound level / noise level datasets with high temporal resolution, that is LAeq at every 10 seconds or more often. The data should cover at least 24 hours in a single location, with multiple days being very advantageous.

Almost all kinds of environment are of interest, for example:

- office/workplace
- construction
- industry/manufacturing
- train/metro traffic
- road traffic
- airplane traffic
- community noise. residential/urban
- natural scenes / rural

Answer (score 2):

From before, we have found the following datasets:

### NTNU Koopen

https://github.com/Faiga91/Koopen

Collected by researchers at NTNU university in Trondheim Norway. 5 sensors covering an open area at the university used by students. For a time period of 6 months. 2 second resolution.